# What is the Arabic saying behind “Angst essen Seele auf”?

Tags: translation, angst-essen-seele-auf

In Rainer Werner Fassbinder’s film *[Angst essen Seele auf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali:_Fear_Eats_the_Soul)* (1974), Ali uses an Arabic saying, in broken German:

> Angst essen Seele auf.
>   (Fear eat soul.)

I wonder if this is rooted in some actual Arabic saying. If yes, what is it (in the Arabic language)?

Answer (score 7):

Well it's one of the common phrases that is used in Arabic language and it's translation is: الخوف يأكل الروح

**Update**,

In Latin letters,
Al-kawf ya'kol Al-rooh.
Or can be written in this way too,
Al khawf ya'kol Al Rooh.